SQL Query Hours subtracted from Request if opened after a certain time and passes next day time
My users create tickets for our quality group to come inspect projects. sometimes they create requests at the end of the day that the Quality team wont get to until the next morning.
Our Quality Team has a Chart that keeps track of the average minutes all requests are open over a 30 day period and this is off due to the tickets created at the end of the day.
I would like to remove time between 3:30PM on creation day the next morning at 5:00AM
This is what the query looks like for the current chart
select created_at, avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF (MINUTE, created_at, last_completed_at)) avg_minutes_open FROM wp_fbs_tasks where created_at BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW() and (description NOT LIKE '%NDT%' or '%Lab%') LIMIT 3;
Thanks in advance for any help provided

What you need to know is this, Timestamp is for 24 hour periods, if you end up rolling into the next day, you need to add a day to the timestamp so it knows its the next day.  This is in references to "They create requests at the end of the day".  This is one of the age old problems, and God forbid they do it on a leap year at midnight.  Perhpas the end of the day is 6PM and my answer is moot, but if you have a 24 hour operation, this is usually the problem.
